Debugging docker image with --network=host not working in VSCode
I am quite new to working wtih dockers
I am able to debug a docket image in VSCode, by remotely connecting to it. I now have a docker image, that has to be started with --network=host.
I was under the impression that it would work just the same, except for the part where I have to map the port, since it is runinng on the host network. But it does not appear to work that way: A popup it shown by VSCode: connect ECONNREFUSED: 127.0.0.1:5678.
In my dockerfile, I have the following lines (small_app is just a loop, printing 'Hello World' every second):
RUN pip install debugpy
CMD  ["python", "-m", "debugpy", "--listen", "0.0.0.0:5678", "--wait-for-client", "small_app.py"]

If I run this using:
docker run -p5678:5678 small_app

debugging works perfectly
but if I run it using:
docker run --network=host small_app

I get the above mentioned pop-up: connect ECONNREFUSED: 127.0.0.1:5678.
I was expecting it to just connect, since the port used (5678) is a port on the host network
When running the small_app on a local conda environment (so not in a docker), VSCode can connect to it, and I am able to remote debug it. And in this case, it also uses port 5678 on the host network
My launch.json looks like this:
        {
            "name": "Python: Remote Attach",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "attach",
            "connect": {
                "host": "localhost",
                "port": 5678
            },
            "pathMappings": [
                {
                    "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
                    "remoteRoot": "/home"
                }
            ],
            "justMyCode": true
        },

I tried solutions like:

omitting the 0.0.0.0 from the portname in the CMD command in the dockerfile
replacing it by localhost or 127.0.0.1

Browsing this website, the VSCode docs and the rest of the internet did not provide me an answer on how the debug a container thet is started in the host network.
Does anybody have any clue how to debug a dockercontainer that is started with --network=host in VSCode?

You should almost never need --network=host, and it doesn't work the way you expect in VM-based environments like Docker Desktop.  Why do you think you need it here?  Can you use the working -p option instead?

Unfortunately, it needs to connect to a message bus running outside the docker network.

There are well-documented paths to doing that that don't require disabling Docker's networking layer.
